# Perl - split command with regex - split numeric and strings

Tags: regex, perl, split

My data look as follows:

```
20110627 ABC DBE EFG
 217722 1425 1767 0.654504367955466 0.811585416264778 -0.157081048309312
```

I am trying to split in such a way that I keep numeric values in one cell, and strings in one cell.

Thus, I want "20110627" in one cell, "ABC DBE EFG" in another, "0.811585416264778" in another, "-0.157081048309312" in another, etc.

I have the following split command in perl with a regex

```
my @Fld = split(/[\d+][\s][\w+]/, $_);
```

But that doesn't seem to do what I want.. Can someone tell me which regex to use? Thanks in advance

EDIT : Following vks suggestion, I changed his regex a little bit to get rid of whitespace, take into account the string might have commas (,) or slash (/) or a dash (-) but then the negative sign (-) seems to be taken as a separate token in numbers:

```
(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)|([\/?,?\.?\-?a-zA-Z\/ ]+)

20110627 A B C
 217722 1425 1767 0.654504367955466 0.811585416264778 -0.157081048309312 
19950725 A C
 16458 63 91 0.38279256288735 0.552922590837283 -0.170130027949933 
19980323 G C I /DE/
20130516 A - E, INC.
 33019 398 197 1.205366607105 0.596626184923832 0.608740422181168 
20130516 A - E, INC.
 24094 134 137 0.556155059350876 0.56860629202291 -0.0124512326720345 
19960327 A F C /DE 38905 503 169 1.29289294435163 0.434391466392495 0.858501477959131
```

Expected output :
20110627 in one token
A B C in one token
-0.170130027949933 in one token
G C I /DE/ in one token
A - E, INC. in one token.. (of course all the other should be in separate tokens, in other words the strings in one token and the numbers in one token.. I cannot write every single one of them but I think it it straightforward)

2nd EDIT:

Brian found the right regex: /(-?\d+(?:.\d+)?)|([/,.-a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[/,.-a-zA-Z]+)*)/ (see below). Thanks Brian ! I now have a follow up question: I am writing the results of the regex split to an Excel file, using the following code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel; 
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Workbook;

if (($#ARGV < 1) || ($#ARGV > 2)) {
    die("Usage: tab2xls tabfile.txt newfile.xls\n");
};
open (TABFILE, $ARGV[0]) or die "$ARGV[0]: $!";

my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new($ARGV[1]);
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
my $row = 0;
my $col = 0;

while (<TABFILE>) {
    chomp;
    # Split
    my @Fld = split(/(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|([\/,.\-a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[\/,.\-a-zA-Z]+)*)/, $_);

    $col = 0;
    foreach my $token (@Fld) {
            $worksheet->write($row, $col, $token);
            $col++;
        }
            $row++;
    }
```

The problem is I get empty cells when I use that code:

```
> "EMPTY CELL" "1000" "EMPTY CELL" "EMPTY CELL" "ABC DEG" "EMPTY CELL"
> "2500" "EMPTY CELL" "EMPTY CELL" "1500" "3500"
```

Why am I getting these empty cells? Any way to avoid that? Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you post an expected output as well.

Comment: I just added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your revised requirements that allow for `/`, `,`, `-`, etc., here's a regex that will capture all numeric tokens in capture group #1 and alpha in capture group #2:

```
(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|([\/,.\-a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[\/,.\-a-zA-Z]+)*)
```

(see [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/cE4eY0/1) example)

Breakdown:

`(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` (capture group #1) matches numbers, with possible negative sign and possible decimal places (in non-capturing group)

`([\/,.\-a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[\/,.\-a-zA-Z]+)*)` (capture group #2) matches alpha strings with possible embedded whitespace

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian. You nailed it. Please take a look in my initial post, I have a follow up question which is related to your regex. If you can help it would be nice. Thanks

Comment: @adrCoder: Try making the current groups non-capturing by adding `?:` right after the open parens. Then add one massive group around the entire regex by wrapping it in parens. If you do that, you shouldn't get empty captures, but you won't be able to distinguish numeric groups from alpha - they'll all be captured by the same group.

Answer (score 2):

This is a broad scoped regex that does whitespace trim.
For some reason Perl always inserts the captures.
Since the regex is basically `\d` or `\D`, it matches everything,
so running split results through grep removes empty elements.

I'm using Perl 5.10, they probably have a `noemptyelements` flag by now.

Regex

```
 # \s*([-\d.]+|\D+)(?<!\s)\s*

 \s* 
 ( [-\d.]+ | \D+ )
 (?<! \s )
 \s*
```

Perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;
my $data = <DATA>;

my @ary = grep { length($_) > 0 } split m/\s*([-\d.]+|\D+)(?<!\s)\s*/, $data;

for (@ary) {
   print "'$_'\n";
}

__DATA__

20110627 A B C
 217722 1425 1767 0.654504367955466 0.811585416264778 -0.157081048309312 
19950725 A C
 16458 63 91 0.38279256288735 0.552922590837283 -0.170130027949933 
19980323 G C I /DE/
20130516 A - E, INC.
 33019 398 197 1.205366607105 0.596626184923832 0.608740422181168 
20130516 A - E, INC.
 24094 134 137 0.556155059350876 0.56860629202291 -0.0124512326720345 
19960327 A F C /DE 38905 503 169 1.29289294435163 0.434391466392495 0.858501477959131
```

Output

```
'20110627'
'A B C'
'217722'
'1425'
'1767'
'0.654504367955466'
'0.811585416264778'
'-0.157081048309312'
'19950725'
'A C'
'16458'
'63'
'91'
'0.38279256288735'
'0.552922590837283'
'-0.170130027949933'
'19980323'
'G C I /DE/'
'20130516'
'A - E, INC.'
'33019'
'398'
'197'
'1.205366607105'
'0.596626184923832'
'0.608740422181168'
'20130516'
'A - E, INC.'
'24094'
'134'
'137'
'0.556155059350876'
'0.56860629202291'
'-0.0124512326720345'
'19960327'
'A F C /DE'
'38905'
'503'
'169'
'1.29289294435163'
'0.434391466392495'
'0.858501477959131'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)|([a-zA-Z ]+)
```

Try this.See demo.Grab the captures.Remove the empty ones.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/35

Comment: I like this, except that the alpha captures would include the spaces at the beginning and end that were really delimiters. Can you change that part of the regex to something like `([a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+)*)`?

Comment: (-?\d+(\.\d+)?)|([\/?,?\.?\-?a-zA-Z\/ ]+) http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/35#pcre I changed ur regex a little bit to capture / and , and . when they are in the string, but it seems to separate the minus (-) from the number.. any idea how to fix that?

Comment: A `?` inside a character class `[...]` does nothing, except match literal question marks.